# Creating time series plot from large csv file

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, weather

I have a large csv file with 3 months of temperature data. Column 1 is the month, column 2 is the day, column 3 is the hour, column 4 is minute, and column 5 is temperature. I am trying to graph all 3 months of temperature data with only the day/month listed on the x-axis. Here is what I have so far:

```
filename ='TemperatureFile.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    month, day, hour, temperature = [], [], [], []
    for row in reader:
        mon=datetime.strptime(row[0],"%m")
        month.append(mon)
        date=datetime.strptime(row[1],"%d")
        day.append(date)
        hourx=datetime.strptime(row[2],"%H:%M")
        hour.append(hourx)
        temp = float(row[3])
        temperature.append(temp)

        datefinal=date.isoformat(month, day)


    #date.isoformat(months, days).isoformat()==    

    fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10,6))
    plt.plot(datefinal,temperature, c='red')

    plt.title("Temperatures", fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('Temperatures(F)', fontsize=16)

    plt.show()
```

I cannot figure out how to combine all of the month/day/hour/minute info so all the data plots and I cannot figure out how to place just month/day on the x-axis.

Comment: Could you proved a couple of sample lines from your csv file and edit your question such that the code looks correct once rendered above as I'm having difficulty guessing where your loop structures are due to the loss of the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you actually need to create a datetime from parts, you can do this:

```
dtms = []
temps = []

for row in reader:
    # split row into its 4 parts
    month, day, hour, temperature = row

    # create base datetime object with the current date/time
    dt = datetime.now()

    # replace current month
    dt = dt.replace(month=int(month))

    # replace current day
    dt = dt.replace(day=int(day))

    ## or, you could replace both at the same time
    #dt = dt.replace(month=int(month), day=int(day))

    # get date object from datetime
    dt = dt.date()

    # get time
    tm = datetime.strptime(hour, "%H:%M")

    # get time object from datetime
    tm = tm.time()

    # combine date and time
    dtm = datetime(dt, tm)

    # add datetime to list
    dtms.append(dtm)

    # add temperature to list
    temps.append(float(temperature))
```

However, it doesn't seem necessary in your case. It's actually much easier to just create one datetime object all at once, rather than creating the base datetime object and adding new parts:

```
dtms = []
temps = []

for row in reader:
    # split row into its 4 parts
    month, day, hour, temperature = row

    # concatenate columns into string
    # assuming the current year is the correct year, you may need to add additional logic to get the correct year
    # also assumes dateparts are properly zero-padded
    dtm = "{}-{}-{} {}".format(datetime.now().year, month, day, hour)

    # convert created string into datetime object
    dtm = datetime.strptime(dtm, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

    # add datetime to list
    dtms.append(dtm)

    # add temperature to list
    temps.append(float(temperature))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! And it will also help me do further projects. I appreciate it!

Comment: I have one question...how did you prevent the time part (H:M) from displaying on the plot? I am trying to understand how this was ommitted but do not see the logic in the code. Thank you

Comment: @jonathon-pelissero: I don't know what you're using to plot, so I couldn't tell you for sure - you should put debugging print statements in to check the final created datetimes to make sure they have time components, and you should check the documentation for the module you are using to plot the data.

Comment: I am. And the axis technically should be displaying the time also but its not. I am using the second code you provided with: 
plt.plot(dtms,temps, linewidth=0.5, c='red')

Comment: Okay, so what was the result of your debugging printouts? Do the datetime objects have a time component if you print them out before plotting? Is plt the plotter module (do you import plt)?

Comment: Yes. The dateime objects have the time component as well. And yes I am importing matplotlib and pyplot and using plt.

Answer (score 1):

I had to play around quite a bit just to get the code you presented to work.

Then I could create a single date from the 3 columns you have.

Finally I focus on the formatting of the plot.

It was 2 questions really.

```
filename ='TemperatureFile.csv'

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    dates_list, temperature = [], []
    for row in reader:
        #Convert your 3 colums of strings into a sinlge datestring.
        datestring = ("{0:}/{1:} {2:}".format(*row))
        # Then convert that into a complete date object
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%m/%d %H:%M")
        # Get the temperature as before
        temp = float(row[3])
        # Add new date and temp to appropriate lists
        temperature.append(temp)
        dates_list.append(date_obj)

# Now have complete lists of date and temp.
# Next focus on the formatting of the plot.
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d') # set the format to print the dates in.
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
days = mdates.DayLocator()   # every Day

fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.85, 0.75])
plt.plot(dates_list,temperature, c='red')

# format the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)    
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)

plt.title("Temperatures", fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Temperatures(F)', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

For more information on how to format your plot, google or search SO for what you want to do and the word matplotlib. That's where I got my example from.

Comment: for datestring = ("{0:}/{1:} {2:}".format(*row)), I am getting the error "IndexError: tuple index out of range" which is similar to the error I had been getting regarding tuples.

Comment: Do you have a small sample csv file to test with ? I would suggest, that to debug the problem, you perhaps add a line `print row` just above the one causing the error. You should get a list/tuple with 4 elements in it. This is rather confirmed by the line `month, day, hour, temperature = row` in the example you say works perfectly. The line you're error occurs on in just printing the first three elements of row instead of assigning all 4 elements to 4 variables. Have you kept the `*` ? as that's important to 'unroll' the list/tuple into the 4 elements. The code pasted worked on my fake data.

Comment: Sorry, my memory is awful. I got the same error with my made up csv file. It was caused by a blank line at the bottom of the file so I just deleted it. Try adding the lines `        if len(row) < 4:<return>            continue` just after the `for row in reader:` line to skip lines in the csv file that have less than 4 items.